# React Native FlatList won't render until I scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native

On my Main Screen I have some search parameters that an user can choose from, like brand and price. If I select any of them and press search it send the data to the Second Screen, to show the list, but It won't render until I scroll on it.

But if I search without setting any parameters it shows the list correctly. Since Im sending the parameters to another screen I thought it should re-render.

The same happens with my sort filters... When I'm on the list, if I select "sorte by price" it won't re-render until I scroll again... What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** im not alone: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13316

Setting removeClippedSubviews={false} fixes the initial search, but the sort filters are still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved by using this on my FlatList: `extraData={this.state}` this way, FlatList knows it has to re-render.

It's in the docs.

Comment: how can we add extraData in functional component (Hooks).?

Comment: @pragnesh They updated their docs, now they use Hooks, so they have an example :) https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist